# 2019 workflow to notify

Tags: links

I am in Sharepoint 2019 and have a workflow to notify users when they need to follow up on a leadership survey. I have the email working, but can't get the link to the actual item to consistently appear in the body of the email.

There is not a task or issue per se related to item, just the need to document what the follow up to the surevey was.

Comment: What is the type(template) of list on which you have attached the workflow?

Comment: So you create in a survey list new survey, workflow runs for new items and you want to send email with the survey url to users? so its list workflow on the survey list?